# How to fetch full balance of address?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, wallets, etherscan

guys! Is there a way to fetch full balance of address in USD? I have a wallet in BSC network and I want to get full balance of it. Unfortunately, ethers library and code

```
const  provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/')
const balance = await provider.getBalance('address');
```

only brings me balance in BNB. But I want to have the full address data: all tokens on it and how much of every token on it. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Debunk Open API provides this functionality: https://cloud.debank.com/#section-openapi

But it's not free.

Comment: I see that third-party apps like DeBunk, Alchemy and etc gives such abilities. But that's it, getting all tokens by account only possible with third party companies?